# Why is my Qt slot causing my program to crash?

Tags: c++, qt, crash, segmentation-fault, signals-slots

So I've written the following Qt slot definition:

(header)

```
public slots:
    void test1();
```

(method)

```
void myClass:test1()
{
   //...
}
```

If I put some code in my slot definition, such as code to display a new window or a new messagebox, the code executes fine. However, if I stick in my own function, such as the following:

```
QString myClass::run_func(QString phase)
{
    myOtherClass* moc = new myOtherClass();
    moc->run(phase);
}

void myClass:test1()
{
   run_func("hello world");
}
```

My program crashes, with the following message:

```
Sleep/Wake UUID: 03C9AE1C-32F3-4F2E-8396-80655C0AE1EA

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000010a08062020

VM Regions Near 0x10a08062020:
    CG shared images       00000001c7eb2000-00000001c7eba000 [   32K] r--/r-- SM=SHM  
--> 
    STACK GUARD            00007fff5bc00000-00007fff5f400000 [ 56.0M] ---/rwx SM=NUL  stack guard for thread 0

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   QtCore                          0x0000000100d0c344 QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendThroughObjectEventFilters(QObject*, QEvent*) + 52
1   QtWidgets                       0x0000000100040f19 QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) + 281
2   QtWidgets                       0x00000001000427b2 QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 1442
3   QtCore                          0x0000000100d0c0b2 QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*) + 114
4   QtWidgets                       0x0000000100096344 QWidgetWindow::event(QEvent*) + 212
5   QtWidgets                       0x0000000100040f2c QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) + 300
6   QtWidgets                       0x0000000100043a1d QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 6157
7   QtCore                          0x0000000100d0c0b2 QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*) + 114
8   QtGui                           0x000000010068c9be QGuiApplicationPrivate::processKeyEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::KeyEvent*) + 190
9   QtGui                           0x000000010068b5c8 QGuiApplicationPrivate::processWindowSystemEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::WindowSystemEvent*) + 840
10  QtGui                           0x000000010067b338 QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 136
11  libqcocoa.dylib                 0x000000010441a4c7 QCocoaEventDispatcherPrivate::processPostedEvents() + 295
12  libqcocoa.dylib                 0x000000010441afd8 QCocoaEventDispatcherPrivate::postedEventsSourceCallback(void*) + 40
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff89c72731 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff89c63ea2 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
15  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff89c6362f __CFRunLoopRun + 831
16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff89c630b5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
17  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff874eea0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
18  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff874ee685 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 173
19  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff874ee5bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8e83a3de _DPSNextEvent + 1434
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8e839a2b -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8e82db2c -[NSApplication run] + 553
23  libqcocoa.dylib                 0x0000000104419d44 QCocoaEventDispatcher::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 2404
24  QtCore                          0x0000000100d0964d QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 397
25  QtCore                          0x0000000100d0c652 QCoreApplication::exec() + 354
26  com.yourcompany.PwrCard         0x0000000100002f8b main + 91 (main.cpp:10)
27  com.yourcompany.PwrCard         0x0000000100002f24 start + 52

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c4c9e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900a8f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900abfb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c4ca662 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff872d243d _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 239
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff872d2152 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c4c9e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900a8f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900abfb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c4c9e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900a8f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900abfb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c4c9e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900a8f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900abfb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c4c9e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900a8f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900abfb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c4c9e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900a8f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900abfb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c4c9e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900a8f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900abfb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c4c9e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900a8f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900abfb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c4c5a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c4c4d18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff89c64155 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff89c63779 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff89c630b5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8e9da16e _NSEventThread + 144
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900a7899 _pthread_body + 138
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900a772a _pthread_start + 137
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff900abfc9 thread_start + 13
```

I have my slot linked up with the returnPressed() signal of a lineEdit. I can't figure out for the life of me why this only happens for user-defined functions. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys!

Comment: Are you saying that if you move the three lines in `myClass::run_func()` into `myClass:test1()` (and remove the call to `run_func()` from `test1()`) that it works and there's no crash?

Comment: In this instance, yes... but I realized using message box code in run_func was a poor choice. I had changed the contents of run_func for the purpose of this question to simplify matters. I just changed run_func (above) to reflect more accurately what I'm actually trying to achieve in my code, which is call a custom class from run_func. THIS code, if put in test1(), will still cause the program to crash.

Comment: Another thing to note, even if I comment out the contents of run_func and try calling it from test1, it still causes the program to crash.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it.. run_func has a string return type but didn't actually return a string. Didn't catch this because there wasn't a compile error.

Comment: but it generated warning for sure ;) (if you have used proper flags)